# how to get object in an array with index in a controller angular js

Tags: angularjs

I need to get object in array for the given index in angular js.

```
scope.storeList = [{
  'id':101,
  'name':indhu
},{
  'id':102,
  'name':selvin
},{
  'id':103,
  'name':indhu1
}];
```

In this if i give index value, it should give the object.
I tried this below code but could not get:

```
var list = scope.storeList[2];
```

Please some one help it.

Comment: angular.js:13424 TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: sure:) But what i have done is correct. it worked after sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

name values should be in string type.

```
$scope.storeList = [{
  'id':101,
  'name':"indhu"
},{
  'id':102,
  'name':"selvin"
},{
  'id':103,
  'name':"indhu1"
}];
 console.log("",$scope.storeList[2])
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax error in your JSON object: string must be between quotes:

```
$scope.storeList = [{
  'id':101,
  'name':'indhu'
},{
  'id':102,
  'name':'selvin'
},{
  'id':103,
  'name':'indhu1'
}];

var list = $scope.storeList[2];
console.log(list); // prints Object { id: 103, name: "indhu1" }
```

---

**[Try it on JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/spLq34d3/)** (don't forget to open console).

Answer (score 0):

you can simple try:

```
console.log($scope.storeLit[2]);


$scope.storeList = [{
  'id':101,
  'name':'indhu'
},{
  'id':102,
  'name':'selvin'
},{
  'id':103,
  'name':'indhu1'
}];

console.log(console.log($scope.storeLit[2]);); // prints Object { id: 103, name: "indhu1" }
```

Answer (score 0):

change indhu and indhu1 to string like

```
$scope.storeList = [{
  'id':101,
  'name':'indhu'
},{
  'id':102,
  'name':'selvin'
},{
  'id':103,
  'name':'indhu1'
}];
```

now its proper JSON format and you can get value from list

```
var list = scope.storeList[2];
console.log(list);
```